# Why does echo output the php end tag?

Tags: php

I have a simple hello world project, 
However when I run it  ;  ?>  is outputted along with Hello World, how can I prevent this?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo "<p>Hello World</p>" ; 
 ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not able to replicate the issue.

Comment: Is it possible that in your original you forgot the closing quotes?

Comment: @Psi what I put was a copy and paste, I'm pretty sure I didnt but yeah

Comment: Can you _check_ whether you put the closing quotes in your original? And in case you wrote that thing on a Mac, make sure you used the right space characters.

Comment: view source, i bet you see all the php

Comment: run your code online on this website:[http://phpfiddle.org/](http://phpfiddle.org/). It showing the correct output to me. Check it there.

Comment: @tim good point. Maybe the code was not even run through the PHP interpreter but served as plain instead. However, this would output one quote char as well.